# access an array from do in background method

Tags: android, arrays, android-asynctask, oncreate

My code is as follows:

```
private class GetMovie extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]>{

    protected String[] doInBackground(String...arg0){
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();


        String url = getResources().getString(urlIds[randomNumber]);
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

    if (jsonStr != null){



            try{        

                JSONObject json= (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(jsonStr).nextValue();
                String MovieTitle = json.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                String MovieYear = json.getString(TAG_YEAR);
                String MovieReleased = json.getString(TAG_RELEASE_DATE);
                String MovieDirector = json.getString(TAG_DIRECTOR);
                String MovieActors = json.getString(TAG_ACTORS);//will need to split actors
                String MovieAwards = json.getString(TAG_AWARDS);
                String MovieGenre = json.getString(TAG_GENRE);

                String[] movie = new String []   {MovieTitle,MovieYear,MovieReleased,MovieDirector,MovieActors,MovieAwards,MovieGenre};
                return movie;
            } catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldnt get any data from the url");
        } 
        return null; 
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);
    }



}
```

I am basically trying to populate the movie array in this background task. In my on create method I am then trying to access it using the following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//Calls task to get json and store in string array
   // new GetMovie().execute();

   GetMovie questionstring = new GetMovie();
   String[] movie = questionstring.doInBackground();
    String Title = movie[0];
    String Year = movie[1];
    String Released = movie[2];
    String Director = movie[3];
    String Actor = movie[4];
    String Awards = movie[5];
    String Genre = movie[6];
```

I am then trying to store each record in the array in Strings. This is all done in one activity. Hope someone can help.

Comment: Sooo...what's the problem? What's the question? Did you check out AsyncTask documentation?

Comment: First call asynctask by doing questionstring.execute(). then do your assignments String Title = movie[0]; in the postExecute method

Comment: I was hoping the new GetMovie().execute(); would let me access the array but it does not.

Comment: Please read the [AsyncTask Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) (scroll down the page)

Comment: don't call `doInBackground` yourself. call `execute` do stuff in `onPostExecute`

Comment: @MMG92 why are you against updating the variable in `onPostExecute()`? Is the `AsyncTask` a separate file or is it an inner-class of your `Activity`?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

replace this:

```
String[] movie = questionstring.doInBackground();
String Title = movie[0];
String Year = movie[1];
String Released = movie[2];
String Director = movie[3];
String Actor = movie[4];
String Awards = movie[5];
String Genre = movie[6];
```

with this:

```
questionstring.execute();
String[] movie = questionstring.get();
```

the .get method waits until the async thread is finished so ideally you should do some other actions if applicable before calling .get straight away

---

alternate method:

```
myActivity act;
 GetMovie(myActivity act){
this.act=act;
}
   protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
act.setMovies(result);
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

create relevant methods in myActivity class like so:

global variable

```
GetMovie questionstring=null; 
String[] movie;
```

on create:

```
questionstring = new GetMovie(this);
questionstring.execute();
```

on destroy:

```
onDestroy(){
if(questionstring!=null)questionstring.cancel(true);
super.onDestroy();
}
```

set movies:

```
public void setMovies(String[] mov){
movies=mov;
textView0.setText(mov[0]);
textView1.setText(mov[1]);
textView2.setText(mov[2]);
textView3.setText(mov[3]);
textView4.setText(mov[4]);
textView5.setText(mov[5]);
textView6.setText(mov[6]);
}
```

Comment: Do you know what would happen if the calls `get()`?

Comment: yes i just added a comment in at the end. there are other methods that could work better dependant on what else he has to do in his main activity.

Comment: Worst possible solution. `get()` would block the UI `Thread`.

Comment: Calling `get()` means that you might as well not have used an `AsyncTask` to begin with.

Comment: it does not "block" the UI thread it causes it to wait which is different.

Comment: Ok, now tell me the difference between "waiting for something to finish" and "it is blocked until something finished"...

Comment: @theellipsis please refrain from giving this kind of answers until (at least) `get()` is asynchronous

Comment: i said in my second comment, that i know what it does... from the example code he wanted to access the array in the on create straight after. and i also said that i was going to suggest a better solution based on when he needs the array to be available.

Comment: What would happen if the `Activity` is finished before `onPostExecute()` gets called?

Comment: asynctask.cancel(true); before you finish the activity.

Comment: Is that part of your answer? Can you please either remove or edit this answer so it makes sense?

Comment: will do, I was rushing as i was getting a ton of comments from people ignoring the second comment.

Comment: Hi Guys I used the first method which was provided and this gave me exactly what I wanted? Is it OK to use?

Comment: I would say it depends if you need to access the array straight away, which is what it looks like from your question, but i would advise my second method.

Comment: what do you plan on doing with the array? placing it in a list view or something?

Comment: @MMG92 you have been given the reasons **not** to use `.get()`. If that's what you choose then that's your choice. But you shouldn't

Comment: Hi I am just outputting some specific values into a textview on screen nothing to complex.

Comment: I have once again done another little edit, I would suggest using my second method, in the setMovie method. it will now update the textViews automatically as soon as the asyncTask is finished. this is better as it doesn't prevent you from doing other things, which is likely to happen as your project becomes bigger.

you could set the text views to loading initially if you want as this will change once the data loads.

Comment: Ok thanks I will be adding a lot more to the project so this will do for now. I will accept your answer as I have been trying for a couple of days and this seems to be the only solution I understand and can implement properly within my project thanks again guys!

Comment: no problem. do remember as your project gets bigger it is advised that you use my alternative

Answer (score 0):

> questionstring.doInBackground();

You should never call `AsyncTask`'s "lifecycle" methods; the system will call them for you. You can get the result returned from `doInBackground()` in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: ...when calling execute().

Comment: I think he knows he should call `execute()`. I believe he commented it out because he was trying things...

Answer (score 0):

You must rewrite your `onCreate` method (and perhaps other parts of your activity's initialization) to work without the data being available. The whole point of using an `AsyncTask` is to allow long-running operations to proceed without blocking the UI thread. If you force `onCreate` to wait until the data are available, the UI will block.

Move the logic that deals with the data (once they are available) to the task's `onPostExecute` method. Alternatively, move the logic into a method in your activity and call that method (with the results as an argument) from `onPostExecute`.